# How to decrypt RSA cipher text?

Tags: encryption, rsa, ciphers

How can I decrypt an RSA cipher text in which I am only provided with a public key and the cipher text.

The person who encrypted it made a mistake in taking the exponent.

Comment: What do you mean by "The person who encrypted it made a mistake in taking the exponent."?

Comment: This belongs on [cryptography.se].

Comment: You can only decrypt it with the private key or with a great effort on cracking it. That's the point of encrypting it.